# Why memory of kube server api in go pprof tool is far less than the memory that actually used?

Tags: go, kubernetes, memory, kube-apiserver, pprof

Our kube api server in master node has one problem recently, its memory keeps growing and will cause OOM kill, now I am looking into this issue and using go pprof tool to check the
memory status, but one thing that confused me is that the inuse_space memory is far less than the memory that kube api server actually used:
[image]

it shows 9124.54MB memory is in using, right?
but from top command in master node and from grafana monitoring, shows the kube api server used nearly 24G.

grafana:
[image]
top cmd:
[image]
idk why there is this difference, Do I misunderstand the inuse_space in pprof profliing?